# Using the noun "familiarity" and the verb "familiarize"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Please consider my following made-up short story:

> That was fifteen years ago! I was good friends with the girl of one relationship, and the guy of another. They each broke up with their respective others, and I introduced them to each other. They started dating. After a short time, they fell in love and got married. Now, they have two adorable children.

I need to know whether it is possible to say:

> I have **familiarized** those couple together. 
>   Or 
>   - I was the **cause of their familiarity**.

Are these two sentences of mine include the natural usage of the words in my question?

If not, please let me know how a native speaker would imply them in an idiomatic and normal English?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither of those is idiomatic. But your earlier form was:

> I introduced them to each other.

There is scope to make it more succinct:

> I introduced them.

Or you could make it more colloquial:

> I hooked them up.

Or get creative:

> I played Cupid for them.

Etc.

For my money, your very first attempt (using “introduced”) is fine.

Comment: Thank you @tkp but what can I say when I want to use the word "cause" or "make" or "bring about" as in my second sentence?

Comment: Hmm. Well for a start, the fact that I have to think hard about how to use any of those three should alert you to the fact that a native speaker (i.e. me!) probably would _not_ use them in the first place, in this context . However, if I was forced to — if you twisted my arm — then I suppose I might reluctantly try things like, “I was the cause of their beautiful coming together”, or “I made their wonderful romance possible”, or “I brought about their union of souls”, or some other such grammatically correct but embarrassingly cloying fluff.